# Drawing a path with "negative" colour in SVG

Tags: html, svg

Is there an (elegant) way to draw a path with "negative" stroke colour?

What I mean is if i have some element in an HTML document (e.g. a `<canvas>` or an `<img>`, and I overlay it with an `<svg>` element. And I want to draw a path in that `<svg>` element. I want the stroke colour to automatically be the negative of whatever is under that path. Of course, this means the colour of each pixel of the path changes as it passes over different parts of the `<img>` element underneath the `<svg>` element.

Comment: Do you mean like this ? http://jsdo.it/defghi1977/8JKE

Comment: @defghi1977 Pretty much. But I see that in your CSS, the `mix-blend-mode` applies to the whole SVG element. I wonder if I can extend the selector so it applies only to a subset of the paths I draw.

Comment: @defghi1977 I just forked your example. It's indeed possible to make the mix-blend-mode apply to a subset of the paths: http://jsdo.it/ksze/GTUN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mix-blend-mode:difference` property to draw path by inverted colors of backward elements(img, canvas and so on), like this.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="http://jsrun.it/assets/G/H/X/X/GHXXX.png">
<svg width="500px" height="500px">
    <path d="M50,50l400,400" stroke-width="100" stroke="#fff"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
  position:relative;  
}
.wrapper *{
  position:absolute;
}
.wrapper path{
  mix-blend-mode:difference;
}
```

http://jsdo.it/defghi1977/8JKE